# телеграм бот отвечает очень медленно может по паре минут не возвращать ответ

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

телеграм бот отвечает очень медленно может по паре минут не возвращать ответ.

Этот же код на компьютере другого человека работает быстро. Переустановила винду. Ничего не изменилось. Что это может быть?

Бот на питоне, библиотека aiogram

Comment: Бот боту рознь. Как и код бота коду бота. По Вашему вопросу можно построить кучу всяких предположений, но они останутся таковыми без технических подробностей с Вашей стороны.

Answer (score 0):

Антивирус, брендмауер, скорость/качество интернета, производительность ПК
Все это может повлиять на задержку получения ответа.
Если с производительностью и с инетом все ок, значит очевидно что-то фильтрует трафик.